# Split numbers before character

Tags: regex

I have a file a text file looks like this :

```
1030Case12

1030ea

10387Case4

10387Gallon

10798dozen12

10798ea
```

trying to make it looks like this:

```
1030

1030

10387

10387

10798

10798
```

How can I do this with Notepad++ in find and replace ?

Comment: [`/^\d+/mg`](https://regex101.com/r/DhWmWD/1)

Comment: Please verify here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to best ask questions on Stack Overflow.  You should also format your code better.

Comment: Are you looking for a regular expression? If so, can you show us what you've tried so far? We encourage question authors to make a prior effort, even if they are a beginner, since there is a nearly infinite supply of learning material on the internet already.

Comment: Find `(\d+).*`, replace `(\1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following setup should work fine:

```
Find:    ^(\d+).*$
Replace: \1
Options: g,m
```

You didn't specify a framework, so it's up to you to adapt it to your current development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Notepad ++ :

```
Find : (\d+).*
Replace : \1
```

Tick the `Regular Expression` checkbox on the bottom.